# Troubleshooting Vignere Cipher using JFileChooser and JPasswordField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser, jpasswordfield

I'm attempting to make a code that will use JFileChooser and JPassword for getting input of encrypted code or code to be encrypted.

Here is the code to be encrypted "Be sure to drink your Ovaltine!" to be saved in a .rtf or a .txt file. The key is "annie". The output should be

> "Fv '$zi (# pzm"| (wy& `%ip(zzm%".

I have two different class files under the project "Password". One class is called "File Opener". It calls the class "Password1".

Here is Password1.java.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

/* PasswordDemo.java requires no other files. */

public class Password1 extends JPanel
                          implements ActionListener {
    private String key;
    private static String OK = "ok";

    private JFrame controllingFrame; //needed for dialogs
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    public Password1(JFrame f) {
        //Use the default FlowLayout.
        controllingFrame = f;

        //Create everything.
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
        passwordField.setActionCommand(OK);
        passwordField.addActionListener(this);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter the key: ");
        label.setLabelFor(passwordField);

        JComponent buttonPane = createButtonPanel();

        //Lay out everything.
        JPanel textPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        textPane.add(label);
        textPane.add(passwordField);

        add(textPane);
        add(buttonPane);
    }

    protected JComponent createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.setActionCommand(OK); 
        okButton.addActionListener(this);
        p.add(okButton);
        return p;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
        controllingFrame.dispose();

        if (OK.equals(cmd)) { //Process the password.
            char[] input = passwordField.getPassword();

            key = new String(input);
            //Zero out the possible password, for security.
            Arrays.fill(input,'0');
            passwordField.selectAll();
            resetFocus();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a key.");
        }
    }

    public String getKey(){
        return key;
    }

    //Must be called from the event dispatch thread.
    protected void resetFocus() {
        passwordField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Key");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        final Password1 newContentPane = new Password1(frame);
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Make sure the focus goes to the right component
        //whenever the frame is initially given the focus.
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                newContentPane.resetFocus();
            }
        });

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the FileOpener.java.

```
   import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FileOpener extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static private final String newline = "\n";
    private Password1 p1;
    JButton decodeButton, encodeButton;
    JFileChooser fc;
    JTextArea log;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    JFrame frame;
    File file;
    int count;

    public FileOpener(){
        // create and set up the window.
        frame = new JFrame("Open Your File");


        // make the program close when the window closes
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // create the box layout
        frame.getContentPane( ).setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane( ), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        //label prompting user for input
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Would you like to encode or decode your file?", JLabel.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label1);

        //create a filer chooser
        fc = new JFileChooser();

        // add a button object
        decodeButton = new JButton("Decode");
        decodeButton.addActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane( ).add(decodeButton);

        encodeButton = new JButton("Encode");
        encodeButton.addActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane( ).add(encodeButton);


        // display the window.
        frame.pack( );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Handle open button action.
        if (e.getSource() == encodeButton) {
             frame.dispose();
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileOpener.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {

                try {
                    file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    p1 = new Password1(frame);
                    p1.createAndShowGUI();
                    //get length of key
                    String key = p1.getKey();
                    int length3 = key.length();
                    count = 0;
                    int keyAsciiValues[] = new int[length3];
                    String name1 ="";
                    //get ascii value of each letter in key
                    for (int k=0; k<length3; k++){
                        char a = key.charAt(k);
                        int ascii1 = (int)a;
                        //put ascii value of letter in key to array
                        keyAsciiValues[k]= ascii1;

                    }

                    FileInputStream file2= new FileInputStream(file);

                    //create a scanner for it
                    in = new Scanner(file2);
                    //read in message
                    String name;
                    name = in.nextLine();
                    for (int k=0; k<length3; k++){
                        char a = key.charAt(k);
                        int ascii1 = (int)a;
                        //put ascii value of letter in key to array
                        keyAsciiValues[k]= ascii1;
                    }
                    //measure length of code message array
                    int length1 = name.length();
                    //measures length of strings in code message array
                    for(int j=0;j<length1;j++){
                        char c = name.charAt(j);
                        int ascii = (int)c;
                        ascii += keyAsciiValues[count];
                        if(c != ' '){
                            count++;
                        }
                        if(count>length3-1){
                            count = 0;
                        }
                        while(ascii>126){
                            ascii-= 93;
                        }
                        char b=(char)ascii;
                        if(c == ' '){
                            b = ' ';
                        }
                        name1 += b;
                    }
                    System.out.println(name1);


                } catch (FileNotFoundException k){
                    //the file was not found!
                    System.out.println("File could not be opened!");
                }
            }

            //Handle save button action.
        } else if (e.getSource() == decodeButton) {
             frame.dispose();
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileOpener.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                try {
                    file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    p1 = new Password1(frame);
                    p1.createAndShowGUI();
                    //open the file

                    //get length of key 
                    String key = p1.getKey();
                    int length3 = key.length();
                    count = 0;
                    int keyAsciiValues[] = new int[length3];
                    String name1 ="";
                    //get ascii value of each letter in key
                    for (int k=0; k<length3; k++){
                        char a = key.charAt(k);
                        int ascii1 = (int)a;
                        //put ascii value of letter in key to array
                        keyAsciiValues[k]= ascii1;
                    }



                    //create a scanner for it
                    in = new Scanner(file);

                    //read in message
                    String name;
                    name = in.nextLine();
                    for (int k=0; k<length3; k++){
                        char a = key.charAt(k);
                        int ascii1 = (int)a;
                        //put ascii value of letter in key to array
                        keyAsciiValues[k]= ascii1;
                    }
                    //measure length of code message array
                    int length1 = name.length();
                    //measures length of strings in code message array
                    for(int j=0;j<length1;j++){
                        char c = name.charAt(j);
                        int ascii = (int)c;
                        ascii -= keyAsciiValues[count];
                        if(c != ' '){
                            count++;
                        }
                        if(count>length3-1){
                            count = 0;
                        }
                        while(ascii<33){
                            ascii+= 93;
                        }
                        char b=(char)ascii;
                        if(c == ' '){
                            b = ' ';
                        }
                        name1 += b;
                    }
                    System.out.print(name1);


                } catch (FileNotFoundException k){
                    //the file was not found!
                    System.out.println("File could not be opened!");
                }
            }

            in.close(); 

                log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
            }
    }


public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
  FileOpener f = new FileOpener();
}    
}
```

It was working fine before I added the JFileChooser and the Password stuff aka there shouldn't be anything wrong with the actual ciphering part of the code.

It's giving me a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at line at line 70 in FileOpener.

```
int length3 = key.length();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `createAndShowGUI()` method, you show your `Password1` instance in a `JFrame`, not a modal `JDialog`. Therefore, this display instruction is non-blocking, i.e. it does not stop code execution, nor does it wait until you click a button that closes the window.

As a result, you retrieve the `Password1` instance `key` before its `actionPerformed()` method can execute and initialize the `key` attribute, hence the `key` is still `null` and you get a `NullPointerException` when you invoke any method on it.

My suggestion is using a modal `JDialog` in `createAndShowGUI()` to manage your `Password1` interface (initialization using a `JPanel` is much like what you are already doing with a `JFrame`). This way, when you invoke `createAndShowGUI()`, the `FileOpener.actionPerformed()` method execution will block until you are done with the `Password1` dialog, hence you will make sure `key` is properly initialized before you retrieve and use it in `FileOpener.actionPerformed()`.

One last thing: be careful with `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`! Using it on your main window is OK but using it on any secondary window will make the whole program shut down completely as soon as you close it. But anyway, the `JDialog` version of `setDefaultCloseOperation()` doesn't accept `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` as a valid argument, so you will remain using it only on your main `FileOpener` window, which is fine.

Comment: I think this is a great answer however I haven't studied JDialog yet! I will do some research though. I really appreciate you answering my question!